# azure finding and removing unattached disks

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to find my disks on azure but I seem to only get one disk when I have around 20 atleast.

The Syntax:

```
Get-AzureDisk
```

Sadly, only one disk is showing which I beleive is from a classicVM.

Can someone help?

Just in case, the syntax to find unattached disk

```
Get-AzureDisk | Where-Object {$_.AttachedTo -eq $Null}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was your VM deployed in Classic model or ARM model?

If the disks were attached to classic VM, and you selected a subscription which has these disks, you should be able to see all of them by Get-AzureDisk command. (The syntax you provided is correct.)

If the disks were attached to classic VM but you are not sure which subscription you have selected, see your current  subscription by **Get-AzureSubscription** command. If you want to select other subscriptions, use [Select-AzureSubscription](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn495203.aspx) command.

If your disks were detached from ARM VM or your ARM VM was deleted without deleting the disk, you can delete disks from **Azure portal** (https://portal.azure.com). Select Storage Accounts, then click on the storage account where your unattached VHD's are located, Click Blobs, click the container containing VHD, search for/click the vhd and click delete.

Note that there’s no direct PowerShell command for getting the Azure ARM VM disks. However, for existing VM and attached disks, you could use *Get-AzureRmVM* to return data disks as part of the VM return, then use *Remove-AzureRmVMDataDisk* command to delete ARM data disks. (This might not apply to your scenario since you are looking for unattached disks.)

Please be sure you select the right subscription and choose a corresponding command/action for different deployment models.

Let us know if it helps. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for responding. I was just looking for the powershell commmand but hopefully you guys would add one in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. The team is working on something similar to Get-AzureDisk. Please keep up with Azure PowerShell future releases. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The syntax looks correct to me. What do you see when you just run the Get-AzureDisk command? AzureDisk retrieves data for all the disks in the disk repository for the current subscription (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn495125.aspx). If the outputs from both command s(the one that you ran and the output of AzureDisks) are the same, you may have selected a subscription which do not have that many unattached disks.

Thanks,
Aung

Comment: Hi,I am trying the Azure Web based CLI to find such unattached disks in my resource-group, but don't see the 'diskState' parameter in the response:

I am in the Azure Web CLI console and executed the command "az disk list --resource-group XXXXXX --query '[].{name:name,diskState:diskState}'  "

Answer (score 0):

The article includes scripts which should help you in achieving your requirement.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/find-unattached-disks

> ```
> # Managed disks: Find and delete unattached disks
> #Set deleteUnattachedDisks=1 if you want to delete unattached Managed Disks
> # Set deleteUnattachedDisks=0 if you want to see the Id of the unattached Managed Disks
> $deleteUnattachedDisks=0
>
> $managedDisks = Get-AzureRmDisk
>
> foreach ($md in $managedDisks) {
>
>     # ManagedBy property stores the Id of the VM to which Managed Disk is attached to
>     # If ManagedBy property is $null then it means that the Managed Disk is not attached to a VM
>     if($md.ManagedBy -eq $null){
>
>         if($deleteUnattachedDisks -eq 1){
>
>             Write-Host "Deleting unattached Managed Disk with Id: $($md.Id)"
>
>             $md | Remove-AzureRmDisk -Force
>
>             Write-Host "Deleted unattached Managed Disk with Id: $($md.Id) "
>
>         }else{
>
>             $md.Id
>
>         }
>
>     }
>
>  }
> ```

Unmanaged disks: Find and delete unattached disks

> ```
> # Set deleteUnattachedVHDs=1 if you want to delete unattached VHDs
> # Set deleteUnattachedVHDs=0 if you want to see the Uri of the unattached VHDs
> $deleteUnattachedVHDs=0
>
> $storageAccounts = Get-AzureRmStorageAccount
>
> foreach($storageAccount in $storageAccounts){
>
>     $storageKey = (Get-AzureRmStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName $storageAccount.ResourceGroupName -Name $storageAccount.StorageAccountName)[0].Value
>
>     $context = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageAccount.StorageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $storageKey
>
>     $containers = Get-AzureStorageContainer -Context $context
>
>     foreach($container in $containers){
>
>         $blobs = Get-AzureStorageBlob -Container $container.Name -Context $context
>
>         #Fetch all the Page blobs with extension .vhd as only Page blobs can be attached as disk to Azure VMs
>         $blobs | Where-Object {$_.BlobType -eq 'PageBlob' -and $_.Name.EndsWith('.vhd')} | ForEach-Object { 
>
>             #If a Page blob is not attached as disk then LeaseStatus will be unlocked
>             if($_.ICloudBlob.Properties.LeaseStatus -eq 'Unlocked'){
>
>                   if($deleteUnattachedVHDs -eq 1){
>
>                         Write-Host "Deleting unattached VHD with Uri: $($_.ICloudBlob.Uri.AbsoluteUri)"
>
>                         $_ | Remove-AzureStorageBlob -Force
>
>                         Write-Host "Deleted unattached VHD with Uri: $($_.ICloudBlob.Uri.AbsoluteUri)"
>                   }
>                   else{
>
>                         $_.ICloudBlob.Uri.AbsoluteUri
>
>                   }
>
>             }
>
>         }
>
>     }
>
> }
> ```

Comment: Nice! Although command lines aren't supposed to be long scripts.:)

Answer (score 0):

to my opinion, this code is clean, simple, and does the job.

```
$disksList =  (Get-AzDisk | select  DiskState,Name,ResourceGroupName | where DiskState -eq 'Unattached')

  foreach($disk in $disksList){

    Remove-AzDisk -DiskName $disk.Name -ResourceGroupName $disk.ResourceGroupName -Force

  }
```